# A closed form for $\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{2^{-x}-3^{-x}}x\right)^adx,\ a\notin\mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, closed-form

Let
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{2^{-x}-3^{-x}}x\right)^adx.$$
$I(a)$ has closed form representations for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

> - Is there any algebraic (or at least [period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods)) $a\notin\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $I(a)$ has a closed form representation?
> - In particular, does $\displaystyle I\left(\frac12\right)=\int_0^\infty\sqrt{\frac{2^{-x}-3^{-x}\vphantom|}{x}}\ dx\ $ have a closed form representation?

Comment: The fact that *a* is or is not a (positive) integer is beside the point, since [Newton's binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) can easily be extended to all complex exponents. The answer is an infinite sum whose terms will probably contain products of [exponential integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: I would not consider an unevaluated infinite sum as a closed form.

Comment: Me either, but since *finite* sums of exponential integrals is what happens for *integer* powers, it's a bit counter-intuitive to expect anything *less* for non-integer powers.

Comment: Vladimir sir, do you mind if I start a bounty on this question?

Comment: @Kugelblitz I do not mind at all.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Alright sir, I'll place a bounty on this after my current bounties are over.

Comment: Btw @VladimirReshetnikov Can you help me with this?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168651/closed-form-of-int-frac-bigl-cos-1x-sqrt1-x2-bigr-1-ln-bigl

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Have you gotten any closer to this question's answer by any chance? Or are you really okay with me starting a bounty for this? All I need is your confirmation..

Comment: @Kugelblitz No, I have no idea how to approach this question. I'm really okay if you start a bounty on this.

Comment: Alright sir! I've started a bounty on this. Thank you for letting me do so.

Answer (score 10):

For $a=1$ we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2^{-x}-3^{-x}}{x}\,dx = \log\left(\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}\right)$$
by [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html). For $a=2$ we can apply integration by parts:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2^{-x}-3^{-x}}{x}\right)^2\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2^{-x}-3^{-x}}{x}(3^{-x}\log 3-2^{-x}\log 2)\,dx$$
so:
$$ I(2)=2\left(\log 3\cdot\log\left(\frac{\log 9}{\log 6}\right)-\log2\cdot\log\left(\frac{\log 6}{\log 4}\right)\right).$$
by Frullani's theorem again. To give an extension of the technique for non-integer $a$, we just need to compute some fractional derivatives/integrals. At least in theory. For $a=\frac{1}{2}$, we just need to compute the [semiderivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiderivative.html) of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ (easy) and the [semi-integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semi-Integral.html) of $\sqrt{2^{-x}-3^{-x}}$ (hard).