# Analytic form of: $ \int \frac{\bigl[\cos^{-1}(x)\sqrt{1-x^2}\bigr]^{-1}}{\ln\bigl( 1+\sin(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})/\pi\bigr)} dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

Background: On my quest to solve difficult integrals, I chanced upon this site: http://www.durofy.com/5-most-beautiful-questions-from-integral-calculus/

Good problems for me, (novice), although I believe these integrals maybe easy for others.

---

I'm having problems with this integral :-
$$ \int \frac{\left[\cos^{-1}(x)\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right]^{-1}}{\ln\left( 1+\frac{\sin(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\pi}\right)} dx $$

---

***My effort***: I tried to convert $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ into '$ \cos(\arcsin x) $' and then simplify, but I couldn't do it.
Then I tried to convert it to '$\sin(\arccos x)$', but it just made it worse.

**Edit**: As Lucian suggested in the comments, I came this far -

$$ \int \frac{-1}{t\ln\left( 1+\frac{\sin(\sin(2t))}{\pi}\right)} dx $$
I would've thought of doing this, if the 'primary sine function' in the denominator was an 'arcsin function'. Problem is, I'm not able to proceed. What do I do?

---

**Question: What is this integral's analytic form? What is the underlying trick/substitution/concept needed to solve this integral?**

---

Note: A non-closed form solution may also exist; I don't know about that. If you do manage to evaluate this integral in terms of even special functions including Bessel, Gamma or Faddeeva, it's okay; you can post it.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $x=\cos t$. Also, are you sure it's not supposed to be $\sin^{-1}$ in the denominator?

Comment: Alright. In the process of solving it...

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining themselves?

Comment: @Lucian No. The problem says sin in the denominator. Check the link out.

Comment: The first integral from your link gives non-simplifiable hypergeometric function by trivial series expansion; fancy coefficients do not play any essential role and only complicate the answer. There are chances that other questions from that site are idiotic even to a greater extent.

Comment: ^Alright. Thank you for the opinion. Any idea how to solve this particular idiotic question?

Comment: Also @O.L. I'm not trying to be rude at all; please don't misunderstand. I'm genuinely asking if there is a possibility to answer this question :)

Comment: There is no reason to expect this integral to have a nice solution. Try to plot this function - it has singularities for all $t = \pi/2,\pi,3\pi/2,\ldots$ and the integral is not finite when integrated over any of these singuarities. Even with Lucian's simplifying suggestion ($\sin(\cdot) \to \sin^{-1}(\cdot)$) the integral cannot be solved in closed form. IMO this is not a very useful problem to be training your skills on:)

Comment: ^I kind of realised that over the past week; I'm just curious as to whether it has an analytic solution, closed form or not...

Comment: @Kugelblitz is it a product of arccos and sqrt(1-x^2)?

Comment: @AdityaKumar Indeed.

Comment: take a look at the risch algorithm if you want to see if a given integral has a closed form expression, its a pretty sick algorithm ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$J(x)=\int\dfrac1{\ln\left(1+\dfrac1\pi\sin\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right)}\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos^{-1}x}.\tag1$$
Firstly,
$$1-\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2 = 1-4x^2+4x^4 = (2x^2-1)^2 = (\cos(2\cos^{-1}x))^2,$$
so
$$J(x)=\int\dfrac{d(\cos^{-1}x)}{\cos^{-1}x\cdot\ln\left(1+\dfrac1\pi\cos\left(\cos(2\cos^{-1}x)\right)\right)}=J_1(\cos^{-1}x),\tag2$$
where
$$J_1(y)=\int\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y\ln\left(1+\dfrac1\pi\cos(\cos 2y)\right)}.\tag3$$
I have not obtained closed form for $(3).$

At the same time, it is possible to obtain Taylor series of
$${\small \dfrac1{\ln\left(1+\dfrac1\pi\cos(z)\right)} = \dfrac1p\left(1+\dfrac1{2q}y^2 + \dfrac{6+(2-\pi)p}{24q^2}y^4+\dfrac{90+30(2-\pi)p+(16-13\pi+\pi^2)p^2}{720q^3}y^6+\dots\right)},$$
where
$$p=\ln\left(1+\dfrac1\pi\right),\quad q=(\pi+1)\ln\left(1+\dfrac1\pi\right)\tag4$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%201%2Fln(1%2Bcos(z)%2Fpi))),
and this approximation leads to the formula of
$$\begin{align}
&J_1(y)\approx\dfrac1{23040(1+\pi)^3p^4}\Big(
\left(90+(60-30\pi)p+(\pi^2-13\pi+16)p^2\right)\mathrm{Ci}(12y)\\
&-6\left(-90 - (90\pi+180)p + (19\pi^2-7\pi -56)p^2\right)\mathrm{Ci}(8y)\\
&+15\left(90+(252+162\pi)p + (464+787\pi+353\pi^2)p^2\right)\mathrm{Ci}(4y)\\
&+\big((23040\pi^3+69120\pi^2+69120\pi+23040)p^3+(5410\pi^2+11750\pi+6640)p^2\\
&+(1860\pi+2760)p+900\big)\ln(2y)+\dots\Big)
\end{align}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20(1%2Fp%2B(1%2F(2p%5E2(1%2Bpi)))z%5E2%20%2B%20((6%2B(2-%5Cpi)p)%2F(24p%5E3(1%2Bpi)%5E2))z%5E4%2B((90%2B30(2-%5Cpi)p%2B(16-13%5Cpi%2B%5Cpi%5E2)p%5E2)%2F(720p%5E4(1%2Bpi)%5E3))z%5E6)%2Fy%20dy,%20where%20z%3Dcos(2y),%20p%3Dln(1%2B1%2Fpi))).